# Class Not Found, but its static methods work

Tags: php

I've stared at this for two hours, and I'm sure there's a decent reason this is happening, but I can't figure it out.

```
<?php
error_reporting(7); //warning & parse

include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/echo/EchoApplication.php');


$db_credentials = array(
    'host'          => 'localhost',
    'user'          => 'db_user',
    'password'      => 'db_pass',
    'database'      => 'db_name'
);

EchoApplication::testMethod();

$app = new EchoApplicaton(); //line 16
$app->db_credentials = $db_credentials;
$app->run();
----and this happens----
Fatal error: Class 'EchoApplicaton' not found in /var/www/html_echo/page.php on line 16
```

How is that possible?

EDIT: posted the whole page's code.

Comment: Are they both running one after the other like in your example?

Comment: Yep, that's line 14-16, with a blank line in between.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
EchoApplicaton
```

You've missed one letter - EchoApplicat >>i<< on

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your class has a [constructor](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php)? I think the `new` statement doesn't work if you are missing one.

[According to the manual:](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php)

> For backwards compatibility, if PHP 5
>   cannot find a __construct() function
>   for a given class, it will search for
>   the old-style constructor function, by
>   the name of the class. Effectively, it
>   means that the only case that would
>   have compatibility issues is if the
>   class had a method named __construct()
>   which was used for different
>   semantics.

Basically, you better either have a `__construct()` or a `EchoApplicaton()` method in your class that is publicly accessible, or an error will be thrown.

Comment: I do, but it's empty. Does that matter? `public function __construct() {}`

Comment: Then that's not the problem... What is the scope of the class itself?

Comment: classes do not need to declare a constructor.  It's there as a utility if you need it, but you don't need to declare one for `new` to work...